# What the difference between miracast and DLNA?

Tags: dlna

can anyone tell me the difference between DLNA and Miracast, especially the technologies underneath?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is an Android related question.

Comment: Miracast was introduced in Android 4.2, where else have you seen it?

Comment: It is like asking about USB cable or GSM antenna or LiON battery, if the question are not Android-specific issue of the technology, they are generally considered off topic. Although the enforcement for these specific kind of questions have been quite lax, and I've been guilty answering a few such questions in the past.

Comment: [This article](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2012/09/19/miracast/) discusses the differences.

Comment: May I/we edit the question to address the user experience and use of these as a way to use an external display given an Android device? That is what I am after and is Android-specific.

Comment: @user29020 ok go ahead. It's closed anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

okay since no one is willing to answer this question, I figured something out myself.

Here's the key points:

DLNA:

- TCP level, HTTP+SOAP interface based on UPnP technology
- pull & push media contents
- remote control play/pause/seek

Miracast:

- transport layer protocol
- AP makes two device handshake, then two device communicate directly via wireless
- not only stream video/audio contents, but also mirro device screens from one to another.